# making changes to a html file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the html file:

```
<!-- sample.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DOM Manipulation Sample</title>
    <script src="dom.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is an H1 heading</h1>

<img src="original-image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
<img src="original-image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">

<h2>Don't Stop</h2>
<h2>Keep Going</h2>

<p>Saksham</p>
<p>Rathi</p>

<div id="div1">
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="makeChanges()">Change</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I have to make a few changes in this HTML file like changing source of images, deleting h1 tags, etc.

Here is the javascript file:

```
function makeChanges()
{
  document.getElementsByTagName("img").src="timepass.png";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1").remove();
  document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML="Enough of JavaScript, let’s stop.";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h2").style.textTransform="capitalize";
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="<h3></h3>";
}
```

I don't know what is the mistake that I am doing

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection ... not a single element - the clue is in the plural `Elements` - and of course the error in your browser developer tools console - did you not notice the error?

Comment: In addition to the comment above, remove is a function so you have to call it: `.remove()`.

Comment: What should I do so that the code runs

Comment: select the first result in each of those .... using `[0]` (and of course CALL `.remove` - though, personally, I'd be using some ID's in the HTML, or perhaps use `document.querySelector` for example

Comment: If [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) was an array (it's not, but disregard that for the moment) how would you access each element in that array?

Comment: @JaromandaX did not work

Comment: @ArkishGupta - you *did it wrong™* - what errors are shown in the console?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByTagName` returns Collection of all tag exists in your html page, you should loop through and then apply changes instead of directly specifying value require to change,

here is the change you should make in your `makeChanges` func.

```js
function makeChanges() {
    const images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (let img of images) {
        img.src = "timepass.png";
    }

    const h1Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    if (h1Elements.length > 0) {
        h1Elements[0].remove();
    }

    const paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (let paragraph of paragraphs) {
        paragraph.innerHTML = "Enough of JavaScript, let’s stop.";
    }

    const h2Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    for (let h2 of h2Elements) {
        h2.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
    }

    const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    div1.innerHTML = "<h3></h3>";
}
```

Comment: It is correct except h2 is not getting uppercase

Comment: Because it is already `capitalize`  seems you are expecting all upper case then you should use **`uppercase`**  use ` h2.style.textTransform = "uppercase";`